# What should we do about closed questions that should be migrated?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-off-topic, closed-questions, migration, ell

I have been part of ELU for about a month and a half, and I have seen many questions closed (usually as unclear but sometimes other reasons) that should have been migrated to ELL. The vast majority of these questions are asked by new users attracted to a site called "English Language and Usage." What should we do about this, if anything?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If a question is closed here, it is generally because it does not meet our quality guidelines.  (See [What Types of Questions should I Avoid Asking](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).)  If it is a decent question that meets the guidelines for ELL (see [Details, Please](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please)), then the people who are voting to close it can and should be selecting "This question should be closed because it belongs on ELL" as their close reason, which will cause it to be migrated automatically sometime after the final close vote is cast.

If the question is about a topic that belongs on ELL, but the question doesn't meet our (or their) quality guidelines, the question should be closed, but NOT migrated.  (See [Please Don't Migrate](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7191/please-dont-migrate) for reasoning.)

If you don't have some specific examples at hand, my inclination is to assume that the questions fall under the "Please Don't Migrate" category.